# How can I allow a user to input values for an array with a specified initial size?

Tags: c

I want to be able to ask a user of this code for four values for an array. I have some code, but it prints an error that I cannot seem to get around. I'm trying to model some of my code after the example in this video tutorial: https://youtu.be/IPYA3b3_nyk?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAKIXv8Yr6nhGJ9Vlcjyymq , however, I cannot seem to get it to compile without errors.

The error goes as follows:
     In function ‘main’:
     intitializeint.c:12:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
              printf("Enter value %d. \n", &i+`);
             ^

I've tried using printf() and scanf() for each prompt for a value but discovered that this tutorial and tried to mimic it. I've tried rearranging the "&i+1" but it just shoots the same error back. I want to have an increment so that in the output, it shows as if the array started at 1.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stddef.h>

 void printArray(int n[]);

 int main(void)
 {
     int i;
     int n[4];

     for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
         printf("Enter value %d. \n", &i+1);
         scanf("%d", &n[i]);
     }

     printf("%s%13s\n", "Element", "Value");
     printArray(n);

     return 0;
 }

 void printArray(int n[])
{
     int i;
     for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)  {
         printf("%7zu%13d\n", i, n[i]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: You go out  of bounds of your array. You have four elements (with indexes `0` to `3`, inclusive) but your input loop goes up to index `4`.

Comment: regarding: `&i+1`  in a call to `printf()` need to pass the actual values, not the address of the values.  Suggest: `printf("Enter value %d. \n", i+1);`  Notice, no `address of` (&) operator.

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {`  In C, the valid index into an array is 0...(number of elements in array -1)  Because in C, arrays are always 0-indexed.  Suggest: `for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {`

Comment: OT:  the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E.  4, 5. 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.   Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wrote `&i` you accidentally created a pointer to `i`.  Your pointer will have type `int *`, because it is a pointer to an int.  The `%d` format specifier expects an int, not a pointer to an int, so that is why the compiler is giving you that error.  (You should re-reread that error and make sure every word of it makes complete sense to you now.)

The solution is to remove the erroneous `&` operator:

```
printf("Enter value %d.\n", i + 1);
```

Comment: this missed the error in the `for()` statement in `main()`